# Resources equvalent in linux. GNU LD

Tags: resources, ld

I need to put some additional data into the final executable of my project.

What I think is a possible solution is somehow to use linker scripts and tell the linker to put file1.raw into address 0x10000. This way I can hope the OS loader will get everything to its place and I will be ale to read from this address?
Is this possible? If so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution based on other threads and some googling.

For people with similar tasks/problems go and check what objcopy does. You can generate .obj from any file and then link it with linker script whenever you want.